# How to use a Parameter Item with Pipeline in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I used Pipeline correctly with the parameter `DropItem` below:

**Items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Website(Item):

    name = Field()
    description = Field()
    url = Field()
```

**Pipeline.py**

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class FilterWordsPipeline(object):

    words_to_filter = ['company', 'economy']

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for word in self.words_to_filter:
            if word in unicode(item['description']).lower():
                raise DropItem("Contains forbidden word: %s" % word)
        else:
            return item
```

Now, I'd like to use the same Pipeline object using the parameter Item, instead DropItem, saving the web site's description only if there are some words filtered thanks to Pipeline.

I'd like to receive the opposite result that I have using the Pipeline detailed above, but I don't know how. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know the best method but you can always `open()` file and `write()` to it.

Comment: why not reversing the filter, Droping the item that you don t wish to save and use the scrapy feed_exporter to write description to a csv file ?